# Objective-C: objective-c response differs from curl response with similar http request

Tags: objective-c, curl, nsurlrequest

Using below curl command I am able to get a valid response with required token.

```
curl -v -h "TOKEN:tokenValue" @“someurl.com”
```

However, When I try to create a NSMutableURLRequest as shown below, I get a different response.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:kURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest addValue:tokenValueStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"TOKEN"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:handler];
```

I have checked the [request allHTTPHeaderfields] and it shows dictionary with TOKEN key-value pair. and Token and url are valid URLs. Theoretically this request is what I am supposed to get the right response but it isnt and I did not find any useful reference online either. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of $TOKEN and `tokenStr`? (Also, I presume you mean -H rather than -h for the curl flag?)

Comment: Those are tokenstrings that I need to pass as a part of the request. yes I meant -H.

Comment: I'm asking to make sure that $TOKEN is "TOKEN:SomeValue" and tokenStr is just "SomeValue"

Comment: my bad. you are right. it is as you described.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a header into curl, you must give the name and value of the header like this:

```
HeaderName:HeaderValue
```

For the Objective-C parameter, you are passing in a value and a name. The value should just be "HeaderValue" and the name would be "HeaderName", which is "TOKEN" in this case.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [urlRequest addValue: HeaderValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"HeaderName"]; because i am already doing that.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your response above. If things are as stated, then the result difference is most likely due to user agent strings. You will need to provide more information in your question to determine that though.

Comment: What information should I provide? Per my knowledge the this is how the request should be constructed in this case. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I agree, this is how it should be dealt with. But we need to know more about what the server is doing. Is this a public server where we can test these things? Can you give examples (stripped of any confidential information) if it is not? If you use Fiddler do the requests look identical? etc.